# Change the step number of displayed images on Pytorch Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I am running tensorboard on a pytorch lightning_logs folder containing some results. However, in the images tab, the batch of images produced are always at step=0 (see attached screenshot). How do I view images produced at a later step on tensorboard? I tried to modify the global_step variable in the image functions in `env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/writer.py`  but this doesn't do anything. I have also attached the command I have run and the contents of the lightning_log folder, as I am unsure if the `writer.py` file I previously mentioned is the one being accessed.

Command: `tensorboard --logdir experiments/lightning_logs/version_8744369/`

Contents of `lightning_logs/version_8744369/`: `events.out.tfevents.1594223100.gl1019.arc-ts.umich.edu.150337.0`,
`events.out.tfevents.1594223139.gl1019.arc-ts.umich.edu.150338.0`,
`hparams.yaml`

[tensorboard output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDQb4.png)

Comment: Post the part where you actually do `writer.add_image(...)`. That will be helpful to find any issues.

Comment: Add part of your code, my guess is that you are not giving the number of the step/epoch:  `writer.add_image(image, step)`

Comment: I don't actually write writer.add_image() anywhere, as tensorboard automatically produces the image summary when i run the command. How would I be able to find where tensorboard is able to find the image data and add that summary?